# Logback RollingFileAppender FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am using `logback` in my `spring-boot` project. When we deploy the app in `PROD` environment, deployment is failed with below exceptions. Before PROD, we deployed the app in lower environments, we did not see any issues. Can someone please throw some light?

In `logback.xml` we have specified the log path as `/app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs/sc-erp-security-permissions-check.log` but from logs below, logpath is set as `/app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs`.

Also attached our `logback.xml`.

```
15:54:22,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: /app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs
15:54:22,305 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [/app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs]
15:54:22,305 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs (Is a directory)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs (Is a directory)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:204)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Logback.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <property name="FILE_PATH" value="${catalina.base}/logs/sc-erp-security-permissions-check.log" />

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %c - %X{TransactionId} - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>TRACE</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="mainAppender"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${FILE_PATH}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${FILE_PATH}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>%d [%t] %-5p %c - %X{TransactionId} - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.adp.smartconnect" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="mainAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </logger>

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.jmx" level="WARN"/>
    <logger name="com.adp.smartconnect.commons" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="springfox" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing" level="INFO"/>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="mainAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @Andreas if you look at our logback.xml file, we set File name as /app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs/sc-erp-security-permissions-check.log. See below configuration. <property name="FILE_PATH" value="${catalina.base}/logs/sc-erp-security-permissions-check.log" />

Comment: @Andreas in btw, this is not causing an issue in lower environments.

Comment: Does the folder `/app/tomcatprofile/micro001/logs` exist, and is the user running Tomcat authorized to write to that folder?

Comment: @Andreas yes that path exists and there are other apps which are writing logs to the same directory.

Comment: That wasn't my question. Is the **user running Tomcat** authorized? Doesn't matter what other programs are doing, because they very likely are running as a different user than Tomcat is, given that standard setups of Tomcat on Linux machines run Tomcat using a dedicated `tomcat` user and group.

Comment: @Andreas user which we use to deploy is a super user and it has read/write permissions.

Comment: Ok, just to confirm terminology: "[Deploy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment)" is the act of *installing* the code, e.g. with Tomcat that word is used for installing a new war file. Even if you were logged in as a superuser when you installed Tomcat itself, doesn't mean that the background Tomcat service process is running as that superuser. If you run `ps -Af`, what user name does it show for the process running Tomcat? On my CentOS, it says user `tomcat`, even though I only ever log in as `root`.

Comment: @Andreas when I ran that command, user I see is 'wasadmin' which is our super user. In btw I really appreciate the time you are putting for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our logback configuration uses spring-boot logback implementation internally, after I removed below line from logback.xml, issue is resolved.

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
```

Note: Our spring-boot version is 1.5.10

Puzzled questions:

1. We still don't know why it is stripping
   "sc-erp-security-permissions-check.log" from complete log file path.
2. With base.xml, deployment was successful in dev, qa and stage but failing only in 2 of 4 nodes in PROD.

I am still doing my research to find out exact root cause, will update this answer if I find something.

Thanks to @Andreas for his prompt responses.

Comment: Did you got chance find the exact root cause ? I m facing the same issue. Its working fine on lower environments but failing on Prod

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem is caused by the running user does not have permission to create the folder containing the log file, which I set it to /var/log/webcast

What resolve my issue is to give permission to the running user in my .service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=syslog.target
  
[Service]
User=webcast
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/webcast/run.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
sudo usermod -aG adm **webcast**
```