# Logback configuration error caused by RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, logback

I'm working on spring boot project deployed on azure server,
I found an error on my logs file concerning logback:

**WARN 146 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
ERROR 146 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: spring.log (Read-only file system)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:169)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)**

and, this is my logback-spring.xml :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEgUg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnrP5.png)

As you can see, i'm not even using **RollingFileAppender** on my conf file, so i don't know why he is telling me that there is a Logback configuration error?

And the second problem, i don't know why the WebApp has restarted?

Java : 11
Spring boot: 2.2.7.RELEASE
Logback : 1.2.3

Could you please help me ?

Thank you,

Comment: Few things.  Did you recompile/mvn clean install before attempting to re-run springboot, perhaps you still have the logback.xml file with file inside your /target folder.   I cant speak for why it restarted...you did not really explain how you are running it to begin with.

If you want to be sure, debug by removing all logback*.xml files, do a clean install, run your springboot app and see if you get the error, then introduce the logback*.xml files again

Comment: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911277/logback-rollingfileappender-filenotfoundexception).